# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError public default void android.content.ServiceConnection.onBindingDied(android.content.ComponentName)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

There is a Unity Program,run in Android.
In Android 8.0,I get this:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError
public default void android.content.ServiceConnection.onBindingDied(android.content.ComponentName)

 bitter.jnibridge.JNIBridge.invoke(Native Method)
 bitter.jnibridge.JNIBridge$a.invoke(Unknown Source:20)
 java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:913)
 $Proxy0.onBindingDied(Unknown Source)
 android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1641)
 android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1674)
 android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
 android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:171)
 android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6684)
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:246)
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:783)
```

Comment: What is your question please?

Comment: How can i find the reason and fix this BUG

Answer (score 2):

That is Unity's bug, out unity version is Unity 5.6.4, if your apk with  INTERNET permission, when google play services crashed or restarted ,the network services will reconnect ,the crash will hapen,You can simulate this process by clearing the Google Play Services data.but I dont know how to resolve it ,Looks like Unity 2018 doesn't have that problem,i send a bug report to Unity ,but no response

Comment: Did you ever figure out if there was a way to fix this without upgrading Unity to 2017/2018?

Answer (score 1):

Got the unity's email :

Hello,

Thank you for your report.

Unfortunately, we no longer support Unity versions lower than Unity 2017.2.
Please update here (TECH): https://store.unity.com/download or here (LTS): https://unity3d.com/unity/qa/lts-releases

The problem is that ServiceConnection.onBindingDied was added in API level 26 and is not implemented before 2017.3 (Which is now 2017.4 LTS), we added this for GoogleAdsServiceConnection in such version and also updated the jnibridge to solve the problem.

If the issue persists after updating, please submit a new bug report describing your problem and how to reproduce it in detail.

Sorry for the inconvenience.

Regards,
Evaldas
Unity Android QA